# NestJS upload multiple files using GraphQL

Tags: file-upload, graphql, upload, nestjs, multer

I tried to upload multiple files using Nestjs Graphql but i can't ..

this code works fine with controller (Rest) exactly in https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

```
   @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files',saveImageToStorage))
  uploadImages(@UploadedFiles() files:Array<Express.Multer.File>, @Req() req:Request):any{
     return ;
  }
```

but it can't work with Graphql may be because (FileInterceptor) can not work with graphql , how i impelment this code or this way with graphql to upload multiple images?

note: I tried many ways to upload multiple images using nest graph(with multer and with graphql-upload) but all ways failed !

image-storage.ts

```
    import { diskStorage } from "multer";
import { generate } from 'shortid';
import * as fs from 'fs';
//const FileType = require('file-type');
import path = require('path');

type validFileExtension = 'png' | 'jpg' | 'jpeg';
type validMimeType = 'image/png' | 'image/jpg' | 'image/jpeg';

const validFileExtensions: validFileExtension[] = ['png' , 'jpg' , 'jpeg'];
const validMimeTypes: validMimeType[] = ['image/png' , 'image/jpg' , 'image/jpeg'];

export const saveImageToStorage = {
    storage:diskStorage({
        destination:'./images',
        filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
            const fileExtension:string = path.extname(file.originalname);
            const fileName:string = generate() + fileExtension
            cb(null,fileName)
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const allowedMimeTypes: validMimeType[] = validMimeTypes;
        allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype) ? cb(null,true) : cb(null,false)
    }
}

export const removeFile = (fullFilePath:string):void => {
   try{
    fs.unlinkSync(fullFilePath);
   } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the AppModule code ?

Have you tried this :

```
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';
...
....
....
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(graphqlUploadExpress()).forRoutes('graphql');
  }
}
```

and in your GraphQLModule parameters :

```
uploads: false
```

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."